# Asking post task questions

Tags: usability-testing, quantitative-analysis, testing

I was looking online to understand what is the best format for post task questions. After each task (There are only two tasks) I want to ask the participant three questions,

1. "How satisfied with the design are you?",
2. "How easy/difficult was the task to complete?" and
3. "How confident were you that you found the right information?"

For collecting and showing results to stakeholders after, Is it better to add a `1-5 scale` for the participant to rate on each of these questions? I can quantify their responses and show a graph indicating the trends between participants. Rather then telling the stakeholders just the verbal answers I receive to the three questions?

Comment: What's the context?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal really is to (only) convince stakeholders, you might be better off by just asking the question with a `YES / NO` option and count the amount of yes vs. no answers.

> - Were you satisfied with the design? YES / NO
> - Was it easy to complete the task? YES / NO
> - Are you confident you found the right information? YES / NO

It's pretty binary anyway. It either is or it isn't.

Besides, going into scales with stars going from 0 to 5 leaves you open for a whole bunch of mediocracy which you then have to explain and find yourself doing a much harder task to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a rating scale at the end of the task can provide quantitative metrics that can be improved upon, like you mentioned. I've found that it also supplements qualitative data, because when a user gives a number that is lower than perfect, they'll often want to tell you the reason, and that's a good data point.

Another way you can run these polls is in this format:

"On a scale of 1 to 5, where 1 is strongly DISAGREE and 5 is strongly AGREE, how much do you agree with this statement? The task was easy to complete." That way you don't get confusion over whether 1 is easy and 5 is hard, or vice versa - they're just telling you if they agree or not.